# How to remove coefficients form R formula string

Tags: regex, r, string, strsplit

I have strings like the following:

```
b="+sl_1__1_1_1+5*from_st_1_4_1_1_1-70*into_st_4_1_1_1_1-sl_1__1_1_2"
b1 ="+sh_8_6_1_1_1-1000*sdp_8_6_1_1_1"
```

I am trying to split it into the following:

```
b:  Variables             Coefficient   
     sl_1__1_1_1                 1
    from_st_1_4_1_1_1            5
     into_st_4_1_1_1_1          -70
     sl_1__1_1_2                -1
b1: Variables                   Coefficient       
    sh_8_6_1_1_1                 1
    sdp_8_6_1_1_1              -1000
```

The strsplit function I am using at the moment is not able to pick up coefficients with more than one digit (i.e the 1000 coefficient).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe `regmatches(b, gregexpr('-?\\w+', text = b))` then put it into a matrix with a conditional to add 1 if there is no coefficient returned between two variables

Comment: how did you get one for the first one? I don't see 1 anywhere.

Comment: @user227710 I guess because `+fg_1` and `+1*fg_1` are equivalent.

Comment: Maybe replace the `+` with `+1*` first? `gsub("\\+([a-z]+)","+1*\\1",b)`

Comment: yes thats right the + results in a 1. Similarly a - results in a -1.

Comment: Yes thats correct -1000. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach with `strpslit`:

```
b= "+fg_1+5*ug1_1-7*tg_4" # original example string

Coefficient <- as.numeric(sub("\\+$", "1", strsplit(b, "\\**[a-z0-9]+_\\d", perl=TRUE)[[1]]))
Variable <- sub("\\+", "", strsplit(b, "[+-]\\d\\**", perl=TRUE)[[1]])
data.frame(Variable, Coefficient)
#  Variable Coefficient
#1     fg_1           1
#2    ug1_1           5
#3     tg_4          -7
```

Explanation of `\\**[a-z0-9]+_\\d`:

- Matches an optional asterisk: `\\**`

  - The end `*` means repeated 0 or more times.  Could easily use `?` for optional instead:  `\\*?`
- Followed by any lowercase letter, followed by any digit 0 to 9: `[a-z0-9]`

  - `+` one or more times: `[a-z0-9]+`
- Followed by an underscore: `_`
- Followed by a digit character:  `\\d`

#### Edit: Update for new sample string with slightly different pattern and a possible constant at the end (e.g. +50 in the below example):

```
# new sample strings
b="+sl_1__1_1_1+5*from_st_1_4_1_1_1-70*into_st_4_1_1_1_1-sl_1__1_1_2"
#b="+sl_1__1_1_1+5*from_st_1_4_1_1_1-70*into_st_4_1_1_1_1-sl_1__1_1_2+50"
#b ="+sh_8_6_1_1_1-1000*sdp_8_6_1_1_1"
#b= "+fg_1+5*ug1_1-7*tg_4"              # 1st sample string from original question

Variable <- strsplit(b, "[+-][0-9]*\\**", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
Variable <- Variable[!Variable == ""]

Coefficient <- as.numeric(sub("([+-]$)", "\\11", 
                 strsplit(b, "(?<=[+-])\\D+.*?(?=[+-]|$)|(?<=\\d)\\*.*?(?=[+-]|$)",
                 perl=TRUE)[[1]]))

# handle possible constant at end of string:
ifelse(length(Coefficient) == (length(Variable)+1L), 
    df <- data.frame(Variable=c(Variable, "constant"), Coefficient), 
    df <- data.frame(Variable, Coefficient))
df
#           Variable Coefficient
#1       sl_1__1_1_1           1
#2 from_st_1_4_1_1_1           5
#3 into_st_4_1_1_1_1         -70
#4       sl_1__1_1_2          -1
```

Comment: Hi, Frank I do not get the same result as you when I run the above script for the Coefficients, I end up with  Coefficient =[1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA] Also can you please explain this section "\\**[a-z0-9]+_\\d".

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I changed the string to b="+sl_1__1_1_1+5*from_st_1_4_1_1_1-7*into_st_4_1_1_1_1+50" but the code does not work for this string so I think I need to modify the above function, just need to understand it a bit better first though. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi Frank, the +50 is not a mistake it is a constant on the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another

```
b <- "+sl_1__1_1_1+5*from_st_1_4_1_1_1-70*into_st_4_1_1_1_1-sl_1__1_1_2"
b1 <- "+sh_8_6_1_1_1-1000*sdp_8_6_1_1_1"
b2 <- "+sl_1__1_1_1+5*from_st_1_4_1_1_1-70*into_st_4_1_1_1_1-sl_1__1_1_2+50"
```

First step, to make life easier, is to add in 1s when no coefficient is given, and then use the regex I mentioned in the comments.

```
(b <- gsub('([+-])(\\D)', '\\11+\\2', b2))
# [1] "+1+sl_1__1_1_1+5*from_st_1_4_1_1_1-70*into_st_4_1_1_1_1-1+sl_1__1_1_2"

(bb <- regmatches(b, gregexpr('[+-]?\\w+', text = b))[[1]])
# [1] "+1"                "+sl_1__1_1_1"      "+5"               
# [4] "from_st_1_4_1_1_1" "-70"               "into_st_4_1_1_1_1"
# [7] "-1"                "+sl_1__1_1_2"
```

then do some final re-arranging and formatting

```
(bb <- data.frame(matrix(bb, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)[, 2:1]))
#                  X1  X2
# 1      +sl_1__1_1_1  +1
# 2 from_st_1_4_1_1_1  +5
# 3 into_st_4_1_1_1_1 -70
# 4      +sl_1__1_1_2  -1

within(bb, {
  X1 <- gsub('\\-|\\+', '', as.character(X1))
  X2 <- as.numeric(as.character(X2))
})

#                  X1  X2
# 1       sl_1__1_1_1   1
# 2 from_st_1_4_1_1_1   5
# 3 into_st_4_1_1_1_1 -70
# 4       sl_1__1_1_2  -1
```

This would be easier to use if you put it into a function. I also added a check for trailing constant terms

```
f <- function(x) {
  ## check constant
  x <- gsub('([+-]\\d+)$', '\\1*constant', x)
  x <- gsub('([+-])(\\D)', '\\11+\\2', x)
  x <- regmatches(x, gregexpr('[+-]?\\w+', text = x))[[1]]
  x <- data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)[, 2:1],
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  x[, 2] <- as.numeric(x[, 2])
  x[, 1] <- gsub('\\-|\\+', '' , x[, 1])
  setNames(x, c('Variable','Coefficient'))
}

f(b)

#            Variable Coefficient
# 1       sl_1__1_1_1           1
# 2 from_st_1_4_1_1_1           5
# 3 into_st_4_1_1_1_1         -70
# 4       sl_1__1_1_2          -1

f(b1)

#        Variable Coefficient
# 1  sh_8_6_1_1_1           1
# 2 sdp_8_6_1_1_1       -1000

f(b2)

#            Variable Coefficient
# 1       sl_1__1_1_1           1
# 2 from_st_1_4_1_1_1           5
# 3 into_st_4_1_1_1_1         -70
# 4       sl_1__1_1_2          -1
# 5          constant          50
```